# Writing a dynamically built DOM for entirety of session once

Tags: php, jquery

I'm grabbing **JSON** from a **rest api** and using the result to build a navigation menu dynamically via **jQuery** which works. However I worry having to repopulate the DOM every refresh or page load would most likely cause a slower user experience...

My question is, instead of getting the data, parsing and building every load. Are there any other ways of storing and implementing this so that the user only has to take the slight dip on first load? I'm thinking of possibly storing it in a cookie and grabbing that but that could be slow too.

To get the api

```
  <?php
   use yii\httpclient\Client;
   $client = new Client();
   $response = $client->createRequest()
             ->setMethod('GET')
             ->setUrl('API_URL')
             ->send();

   if ($response->isOk) {
       $page = $response;
      }
   $retJSON = $response->content;

   $decode = json_decode($retJSON, true);
   $page=$decode;
  ?>
```

To parse and build the data

```
<script async>
  <?php $page = json_encode($page); ?> 
   var json = '<?php print $page; ?>';
   $amtmenu = "";
        $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, obj) {
          if(obj.menu_item_parent == 0){
            if(obj.type != 'custom' | obj.title == 'More'){
              $amtmenu += '<li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'+ obj.title +'<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu ldrop" id="' + obj.ID +'"></ul></li>';
            } else {
              $amtmenu += '<li><a href="'+ obj.url + '">' + obj.title + '</a></li>';
            }
          } 
        });

        $(".navbar-nav").html($amtmenu);

        $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, obj) {
          if(obj.menu_item_parent != 0){
            $itemparent = obj.menu_item_parent;
            $('#' + $itemparent).append( '<li><a href="'+ obj.url +'"> ' + obj.title + ' </a></li>');
          }
        });
    </script>
```

Which builds something like

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Leasing<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu ldrop">
          <li><a href="/leasing/personal-leasing">Personal Car leasing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/leasing/business-leasing">Business Car Leasing</a></li>
          <li><a href="/leasing/van-leasing">Van Leasing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/special-offers">Special Offers</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/services"> Overview </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Leasing Guide<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/leasing-guide"> The Guide </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: you could use localstorage perhaps to store the HTML. But really, is it actually that slow to run some script? You mention a worry, but not any actual test data which demonstrates a performance problem. The other thing you could potentially do is build the menu structure in PHP instead, then the HTML comes to the client ready-rendered. Since you're just injecting the JSON into the page anyway and not using AJAX, I don't see any obvious reason why you couldn't do that. There's a chance that _would_ make it a touch faster, although JS is pretty quick these days.

Comment: Or perhaps, since I just noticed on the PHP side you're actually calling another URL to get the data, maybe an option would be for PHP to cache the result of that into the session, and save yourself the extra HTTP call each time. That might actually be a better time-saver. I hadn't quite appreciated that fact when I wrote my first comment.

Comment: @ADyson The idea of caching server side seems befitting actually, when the API changes, update the JSON response in a file so I can parse the data locally instead of calling other URLs. I haven't gotten a noticeable speed difference on my machine, the majority of our users connect with 3G and that URL call takes around 0.5s extra which might cause drop-offs. I really appreciate your help I'll put it into practise - thank you!